# Can't access website from outside the LAN

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I am trying to setup a LAMP server on my ubuntu 14.04 desktop.
I use a cisco 2320 modem.
I have succesfully tested it across my LAN. I bought a free domain name from noip.com, steveatw.ddns.net.
My public IP as Google and other websites like whatismyip.com tell me is `116.68.120.233`.

So I point my domain name to my public IP that is 116.68.120.233.
And I checked using 
`nslookup steveatw.ddns.net` and the response was my public IP.
But when I try to load my website using my browser there is no response.
So I try to trace the request using `traceroute to steveatw.ddns.net (116.68.120.233), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.2.71.1 (10.2.71.1)  183.309 ms  183.289 ms  183.392 ms
 2  111.231.88.202.asianet.co.in (202.88.231.111)  183.373 ms  183.499 ms  183.478 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *`

Here asianet is my service provider.

Then I checked around my modem settings and made sure I had forwarded the ports and it showed that port 80 is forwarded for the IP 192.168.0.10, which is my local IP.

So I then check around modem settings and find an IP address namely WAN IP address and I go to noip.com where I have my domain at and point my domain at this WAN IP address. And voila the website is successfully launched from the browser. I checked from 3 different devices connected in my LAN and when I type `steveatw.ddns.net` into my address bar of the browser it is being redirected to the webpage I set up.
But when I try to access the website from outside my LAN for e.g. my mobile phone's 3g network I can't seem to access it.
Then I tried to trace the route. And here is what I got:

```
traceroute steveatw.ddns.net
traceroute to steveatw.ddns.net (100.96.21.16), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  * * *
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
```

When I try to ping the same IP it is also successful when trying it from inside the LAN.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: 116.68.120.333 is not a valid IP

Comment: Why is that? thats what i get when i search for my public ip.

Comment: IPs only allow parts up to 255. 333 is out of that range.

Comment: I'm just a novice in this areas. So why is public ip being shown as such? I used http://www.whatsmyip.org/ , and the ip they give is 116.68.120.333.

Comment: Try myip.is instead of whatsmyip.org

Comment: This is what i got from myip.is`Your IP address is:

116.68.120.233

Your Hostname is:

116.68.120.233'

Comment: There we go :) Its 233 and not 333 for the last part. I ran that IP through my analyzer and it seems that you are using satellite internet. Most satellite providers do CGN (Carrier Grade NAT) which means its not possible to run a service behind that provider.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Sorry. So there is no way i can run a web server from my computer ? also can you tell me what ip analyzer you use?

Comment: Also when i use 100.96.21.16 as my ip , i am able to access steveatw.ddns.net from inside my LAN network, So it means atleast the domain name translation is working ,isn't it?

Comment: If you have a decent ISP then they would not put customers behind a CGN without giving them IPv6 access at the same time. If you have IPv6 access, then you can put your IPv6 address in DNS to make the site available from outside. If you only have IPv4 access through a CGN and no IPv6 access at all I would consider it an unacceptably poor connection and start looking for a better provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100.64.0.0/10 is CGN-Space. That means you share your public IP with many other clients and the packets for your shared public IP get blocked at provider level. To circumvent this you have two options: Get your provider to install another forwarding rule on his router or buy a cheap VPS (5$/month DigitalOcean Droplet would do) and build a VPN between the VPS and you.

Comment: Thanks for your taking the time to answer. I did not get it completely but i understand the problem better than before. cheers :) Also can you link me to a tutorial on how i would go about setting up the vps.

Comment: The other option is to use your IPv6 address. If you are stuck behind large scale NAT then your ISP _should_ have given you IPv6.